# Baking materials to make them usable in game engine

Tags: texturing, materials, game-engine

When trying to make a model for a game I have to make materials into textures and I found this really nice tutorial (this https://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/07/16/Baking-Blender-materials-to-texture-to-make-them-usable-in-a-game-engine.aspx) but it isn't working and seems to have options that I apparently don't have, could someone help me with doing this or updating it, but if it already has been put up somewhere can you guide me to it?

Comment: Please read: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/what-is-the-problem-with-posting-an-image-or-link-and-asking-how-do-i-do-this

Comment: this tutorial works on any blender in the 2.7xxx branch
what you really need is to first get the basic knowledge to use blender, I just made the step-by-step tutorial as the game from scratch guy did and it worked in blender 2.5, 2.62, and and 2.79b.